# Sass/Compass Getting variable name from variable

Tags: sass

I'm trying to make a mixin that will let me create adapted blocks of code depending on what variable name you up in.

```
$foo: #00A9EC;
@mixin menu-color($color) {
.color-#{$color} a.level2,
.color-#{$color} a.level2:visited {
    color: $color;
    &:hover {
        color: adjust-lightness($color, 10); }
    &:active {
        color: adjust-lightness($color, -10); } } }

@include menu-color($foo);
```

outputs:

```
.color-foo a.level2,
.color-foo a.level2:visited {
    color: #00A9EC; }

.color-foo a.level2:hover,
.color-foo a.level2:visited:hover {
        color: #20C0FF; }

.color-foo a.level2:active,
.color-foo a.level2:visited:active {
        color: #0084B9; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not name CSS classes after specific colors. You would regret that. Just think, if you want to make the color red later on, you would need to go back over all your html and change the classes.

The reason we have CSS is so that you don't have to embed style information in the markup.

Use a semantic class the describes the data, not how it is displayed:

```
$foo: #00A9EC;

@mixin menu-color($name, $color) {
.custom-#{$name} a.level2,
.custom-#{$name} a.level2:visited {
    color: $color;
    &:hover {
        color: adjust-lightness($color, 10); }
    &:active {
        color: adjust-lightness($color, -10); } } }

@include menu-color(profile, $foo);
```

And then in your HTML `<div class="custom-profile">`.

That way, two years from now when you want to make it black, and underlined (or whatever), you don't have to dig through your html and add a new '.underlined-and-black-color` class to all of those elements. You just change your SCSS in one place.

Comment: The OP doesn't necessarily say he wants to use the *name* of a color, but the solution is the same:  you must pass what you want to call it along with the value it should be.  A variable only knows what value it contains, it doesn't know that you refer to it as `$foo` or `$highlight` or `$major` or anything like that.

Comment: ok, so there is no way of just taking the 'foo' out of '$foo' and printing that?

Comment: No.  This isn't even a limitation of Sass.  None of the languages I know can do that.

Comment: Actually php has this kind of functionality. In php you declare a variable with one dollar sign: $my_var. If you want to get the name of the variable you can append one more dollar sign and there you have it: $my_var_name = $$my_var
It would be nice if sass allowed for this kind of functionality.

Comment: @cimmanon C# has the nameof() expression which can return the name of a variable.

Comment: By all respect, such recommendation like this marked answer create wrong assumptions on readers regarding how to do things with CSS. There's NOT ONE way to do things. That's the great on creativity. There are CSS frameworks exactly taking the opposite & promote you only need to work with HTML like in the early days. Useful for PHP frameworks & some Javascript frameworks do it too. The example to change color, which has been read sooo many times, it is so simple to change color in HTML and it is always best to check manually anyway. Unless you have a flat/boring 3 colors profile without shades.

Answer (score 4):

In sass you can do this using map, you just pass the variable name instead of the variable itself:

```
$colors: ( 
    -black: #000,
    -blue: #088DC6
);

@mixin generateBgColor($colorName) {
    .bg-color#{$colorName} {
        background-color: map-get($colors, $colorName);
    }
}

@include generateBgColor("-blue");
```

This will generate class:

```
.bg-color-blue {
    background-color: #088DC6;
}
```

You achieve this also in less with standard variables, just by using curly brackets and double at character:

```
@blue: #088DC6;

.generate-bg-color(@color) {
    .bg-color-@{color} {
        background-color: @@color;
    }
}

.generate-bg-color(~"blue");
```