# SASS Mixin - Use variables to populate class name

Tags: sass

I have several colours set up as classes

```
.black {background: $black;};
.red {background: $red;}
.yellow {background: $yellow;}
.grey {background: $grey;}
.white {background: $white;}
.blue {background: $blue;}
.full-black {background: #000;}
.light-black {background: #222;}
```

but i want to create a mixin which takes the class name and automatically creates the class name and fills in the background colour so i don't have to type this out every time..

I have tried something like this

```
@mixin colours ($black,$full-black,$light-black,$red,$blue,$yellow,$white,$grey) {
    .(colours): background:{colours};
}
```

But can't figure out the right code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16126625/2168947

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in Less also? Please clarify.

Comment: You dont need a mixin but each, look at my response ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use "associative array" to define the name of your colors and the code:

```
$colors: ("emerald": "#2ecc71", "carrot": "#e67e22");

@each $name, $hexa in $colors {
    .#{$name} {
      color: #{$hexa};
    }
}
```

I made a simple codepen to show you: http://codepen.io/pik_at/pen/MYGJqY